# Jacoco-it.exec not getting generated for integration test

Tags: java, maven

I have multi module project -
    Parent
     1- controller module  - has unit tests
     2- service module - has unit tests
     3- integration test module - Rest assured Api testing

I have integrated jacoco in parent's pom.xml.
Jacoco.exec are getting generated for all the unit tests but jacoco-it.exec not getting generated for integration test module. However surefire-reporst are getting generated. Please suggest if I am missing anything? Do I need to add anything on integration-test-module's pom.xml ? All my plugins are in parent's pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>

                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                    <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>post-integration-test</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                 <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>

                    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>integration-tests</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                    <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@{failsareArgLine}` in the failsafe configuration argLine property, as cited [in the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/faq.html#late-property-evaluation) (so basically an @ instead of $), otherwise failsafe will not use the property set by JaCoCo. In my project, at least, this was the only thing that was missing.